# How to configure varnish with ssl termination on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: varnish

I have a setup running on a Ubuntu 18.04 OS. Also setup server with Apache2 and SSL. I have installed Varnish but not sure how to set it up with SSL without using Nginx.

Basically, I want to setup the PWA so I need a SSL with Varnish cache.

Really appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Hitch

You can use [Hitch](http://hitch-tls.org/) to terminate TLS. Hitch was developed by Varnish Software and its sole job is to be a TLS proxy.

You can easily install Hitch on Ubuntu *18.04* by running the following command:

```
apt-get install -y hitch
```

You can put the following configuration in `/etc/hitch/hitch.conf`:

```
frontend = {
    host = "*"
    port = "443"
}

#When using TCP/IP
backend = "[localhost]:8443"

#When using Unix Domain Sockets
#backend = "/run/varnish.sock"

pem-file = "/etc/hitch/certs/cert.pem"

proxy-proxy = on

ciphersuites = "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256"

ciphers = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"

tls-protos = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3

ecdh-curve = "X25519:prime256v1:secp384r1"

prefer-server-ciphers = false
```

In this example the certificate is located under `/etc/hitch/certs/cert.pem`. Make sure this file exists and contains the right certificate information. [The Hitch docs](https://github.com/varnish/hitch/blob/master/hitch.conf.man.rst) contain a lot more information on certificate configuration, in case you need more flexibility.

Connecting to Varnish can either be done through TCP/IP or Unix Domain Sockets. Select the prefered `backend` config in the example above.

### Varnish 6 & Unix Domain Sockets

If you've installed *Varnish 6*, you can even connect Hitch to Varnish using Unix Domain Sockets, which eliminates the potential overhead of *TCP/IP*.

> If you installed Varnish from Ubuntu's package repository *(which is Varnish 5.2.1)*, you can upgrade an official packaged version of Varnish 6 by going to https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish60lts.
>
> All versions prior to 6.0 are *end-of-life*, upgrading to Varnish 6 doesn't just make sense from a *UDS* point of view, but also from security and stability point of view.

In order to make sure Hitch can properly proxy requests using the [PROXY protocol](https://github.com/varnish/hitch/blob/master/docs/proxy-protocol.md), you'll need to adjust Varnish's runtime parameters:

These are the default settings:

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
```

You'll need to adjust the `-a` listener settings as follows:

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -a uds=/run/varnish.sock,PROXY,user=vcache,group=varnish,mode=660  -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,256m
```

The 3 `-a` declarations do the following:

- Listen on port 80 for regular HTTP connections
- Listen on port 8443 for incoming TCP/IP connections using the PROXY protocol
- Listen on /run/varnish.sock for incoming UDS connections using the PROXY protocol

### Conclusion

Hitch is Varnish's goto TLS proxy that offers very low overhead, that is flexible, but still easy to configure.

By using the *PROXY protocol*, the original client IP is automatically transmitted, and Varnish automatically sets it as the `X-Forwarded-For` value.

If you want to use Unix Domain Sockets, to further lower the overhead, Varnish 6 offers you these capabilities

### What if you don't want a TLS proxy

Nearly all solutions involving TLS and Varnish boil down to using a TLS proxy.

If you really, really, REALLY don't want to use a TLS proxy, you can use [Varnish Enterprise](https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/varnish-enterprise-6.0.6r2). It is not free and open source, but it offers a native-TLS implementation.